# How accurate does corner angle measurement on crown moulding need to be?

Tags: trim, measuring, angle

How accurate does angle measurement on crown moulding corners actually have to be? What I am saying is say compare a manual angle finder that has 1 degree increments vs a typical digital one that would have tenths measurements (40.1,40.2,etc). It appears that digital one would be more accurate because more detailed measurements can be made,but I have seen where they have a plus or minus error of .3.  If you was to cut crown moulding using either of these tools would you notice much difference in the resulting corner made from these two pieces?

Comment: Does the saw You are using have smaller than 1 degree increments?

Comment: you should typically be back-cutting enough that such minor diffs won't matter. if you have multi-faceted shapes like a floating octagon it matters a lot, but most corners aren't even 90.00deg anyway...

Comment: @Kris No. It is Dewalt Dw709 miter saw.

Comment: So it doesn’t matter how accurate your angle finder is you just go with the nearest increment of one degree

Answer (score 2):

Cannot really answer your question because everything depends on you no matter what tool you use. Here are the four main factors:

1. How crafty you with the tool when taking the measurement. Holding, sighting and marking are all part of this.
2. What type of saw and saw fixturing you use to make the molding cuts.
3. How you handle and use the saw tool.
4. And to a lesser degree the type of molding materal used.